# Is there any known fix for Rockstar game launcher?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2, rockstar-games-launcher

I have bought Red Dead Redemption 2 from Rockstar using the official game launcher, however the launcher keep on crashing, throwing "Rockstar launcher exited unexpectedly" error and often even throws heap corruption error when trying to load RDR 2.

Is there any known solution for this situation as I do not want to disable my anti virus. My gpu drivers are up to date and so is my Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did some testing after I read comments on Reddit posts. 
Turns out, **my speaker is the cause for the issue**. Whether it's the Realtek drivers, Sonic Studio 3, or other drivers, I do not know - every sound device I plug into my machine crashes the launcher and the game.
When I unplugged my stereo speakers, everything worked fine again.

**EDIT 2**
Tested some more. Launcher has problems with realtek audio driver that causes the crash. Just switch to any other driver rather then realtek and it will work fine. 
Switched to my Asus rog PG348Q monitor speaker and everything worked fine.

**EDIT 3**
More testing discovered, that your default sound format should be 24 bits 48000hz, else the game crashes.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As [the official Rockstar support page for this error](https://support.rockstargames.com/articles/360037892194/Red-Dead-Redemption-2-on-PC-exited-unexpectedly) mentions, you can try either of the following:

> **Update your graphics drivers**
>
> NVIDIA owners should update their graphics driver version to 441.12 or above in the GeForce Experience app, or manually using [this link](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx).
>
> AMD owners should update their graphics driver version to 19.11.1 or above in the Radeon Software app, or manually using [this link](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download).

and

> **Run RDR2.exe as an administrator**
>
> 1. Open the Rockstar Games Launcher
> 2. Select Settings
> 3. Select Red Dead Redemption 2 under My installed games
> 4. Select Open under View Installation Folder
> 5. Right-Click on RDR2
> 6. Select Properties
> 7. Under the Compatibility Tab
> 8. Select Run this Program as an Administrator (and disable Full Screen Optimization)
> 9. Click OK
> 10. Return to the Games Menu in the Rockstar Games Launcher
> 11. Launch the game

---

**Update:** It seems a lot of people have (had) the same problem with the Rockstar Launcher. There had been several updates since RDR2 was released to fix the problem, but [it still didn't work for many up to at least a week ago](https://www.reddit.com/r/reddeadredemption2/comments/drzghz/pc_rockstar_launcher_exited_unexpectedly/). So, at this point, your best best is to **keep updating the Launcher** until it works. The current version is [1.0.14.181](https://support.rockstargames.com/articles/360038529474/Rockstar-Games-Launcher-Release-Note-v1-0-14-181).

---

**Update 2**: Or you can [try a clean Windows install](https://www.pcgamesn.com/red-dead-redemption-2/pc-fix-rockstar-launcher-exited-unexpectedly) :)

Comment: All is updated, launcher still crashed. Mentioned in the question.

Comment: And the second part? Did you try running the Launcher with Administrator rights?

Comment: Yes, the launcher crashed. The one time it didn't, it said to disable any compatability changes. ‍♂️

Comment: Administrator rights have little to do with compatibility modes, though. It crashes without the 'Full Screen Optimization' disabled as well?

Comment: Yes, it does crash.